# Is $ \int_0^x \left|\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right| \, \mathrm{d}t > C \log(x)$ true? Where $C$ is some constant.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

I am CS major, and I am learning math by my interest.

I am learning Baby Rudin recently, and there is a problem in Chapter 8 Ex 21. The problem asks me to prove there is a constant $C$ such that

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi |D_N(t)dt|  = L_N > C \log N
$$
where
$$
D_N(t) = \sum_{n=-N}^N e^{int}
$$
$N$ is a non-negative integer

Currently, I have proved

$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi |D_N(t)|dt \geq 2 \int_{0}^{(N+1/2)\pi} \left| 
\frac{\sin u}{u}\right| du
$$

Thus I am wondering how to prove

$$
\int_{0}^{(N+1/2)\pi} \left| 
\frac{\sin u}{u}\right| du > C \cdot \log N
$$

Thus, the current question is

Let

$$
f(N) = \int_0^{(N+1/2)\pi} \left|\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right| \, \mathrm{d}t
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
g(N) = \log N.
$$

Does there exist a constant $C$ such that

$$
f(N) > Cg(N)
$$

for $N = 1,2,3,...$

I have tried to use programming to examine this result, and it seems correct, but I havn't found a proof for it.

Comment: Do you know the proof that $f(x)$ diverges to $\infty$? This proof essentially gives the harmonic series $\sum_{k\le x/\pi} 1/k$ as a lower bound which behaves like $\log(x)$.

Comment: Thanks Jochen, I will check out that proof.

Comment: $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is a decreasing function which is close to $1$ when $x\sim 7\pi$

Comment: Hi Claude, thanks for your reply, but I am confused that how does this property help the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

$$
\int_0^{2N\pi} |\frac{\sin(u)}{ u}|du =
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi} |\frac{\sin(u)}{ u}|du
$$

$$
\geq \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{2(k+1)\pi} \int_{2k\pi}^{2(k+1)\pi} |\sin u|du 
$$

$$
=
\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{2(k+1)\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |\sin u|du 
$$

$$
= 
\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(k+1)\pi} 
$$

Because

$$
\log(N) = \int^{N}_1 t^{-1}dt \leq \sum_{k=1}^{N} k^{-1}
$$

Then

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N} ((k+1)\pi)^{-1} \geq (2\pi)^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{N} k^{-1}
$$

Thus

$$
\int_0^{2N\pi} |\frac{\sin(u)}{ u}|du > C \log(N)
$$

$$
\int_0^{(N+1/2)\pi} \left|\frac{\sin(u)}{ u} \right|du  >
\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{2(2N+1)\pi} \left|\frac{\sin(u)}{ u}\right|du
> \frac{C}{4} \log(2N+1)
> \frac{C}{4} \log(N)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint given by Jochen, I think this proof should work.

Comment: Why would $2N\pi +p/q$ be the general case? Do you mean that any positive real number can be written in such form?

Comment: Thanks fore the correction, and I realized I can't generalize it to all positive numbers. So I edit the question and proof, so that it works for all $x = (N+1/2)\pi$